# Why is the variable counter 0 all the time?

Tags: c#

In the User Control code im doing in the top:

```
int counter;
```

In constructor:

```
counter = 0;
```

In the MouseDown event im doing:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);

            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                if (m_itemIndexes.Contains(index))
                    return;

                m_itemIndexes.Add(index);
                DrawItem(index);
                counter += 1;
            }
```

I used a breakpoint on the counter += 1; and saw that it's growing by one each time i click the right mouse button.

Then i add in the bottom a property for the counter:

```
[Browsable(true)]
        public int RedCounts
        {
            get { return counter; }
            set
            {
                counter = value;
                Refresh();
            }
        }
```

Then in Form1 in the top i did:

```
ListBoxControl lb1;
```

In constructor:

```
lb1 = new ListBoxControl();
```

Then in the bottom of Form1 i added:

```
private void deleteSelectedLightningsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure you want to delete " + lb1.RedCounts + " the selected files ? Click Yes to Confirm and No to continue", "WinForm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
                {

                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
```

But the result of RedCounts is all the time 0 i don't know why.

EDIT:

I found that if im doing instead of counter = 0; doing counter = 1; and instead of counter += 1; doing RedCounts += 1; Then using a breakpoint on the RedCounts i see that counter is growing by 1 starting from 1. 1,2,3,4....

The problem for some reason is in Form1 when i click the deleteSelectedLightningsToolStripMenuItem_Click using a breakpoint then lb1.RedCounts is 1 for some reason it's getting the value of 1 maybe from the property or from the line counter = 1; im not sure why. So if i set counter = 121; then lb1.RedCounts will show me 121. Strange.

This is the the full User Control with the counter and RedCounts:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------
 * Module Name  : ListBoxControl
 * Description  : Change listBox items color
 * Author       : Danny
 * Date         : 30/12/2012
 * Revision     : 1.00
 * --------------------------------------------------------------*/

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

/*
 *  Introduction :
 * 
 *  By default the color is red.
 *  Added a property to change the color.
 *  Right mouse click on item to change item color.
 *  Left mouse click on item to change the item color back.
 *  If the listBox is empty the control will be filled with 10 "Test" items.
 * */

namespace Lightnings_Extractor // to check how and change the namespace to listBoxControl
{
    public partial class ListBoxControl : UserControl
    {
        private Color m_MyListColor;
        private List<int> m_itemIndexes = new List<int>();
        private List<int> m_coloringItemIndexes = new List<int>();
        private int counter;
        public event EventHandler<ItemEventArgs> ItemRemoved;

        public List<int> Indices
        {
            get { return m_itemIndexes; }
        }

        public ListBoxControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            counter = 1;
            if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add("Test " + i);
                }
            }
        }

        private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);

            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                if (m_itemIndexes.Contains(index))
                    return;

                m_itemIndexes.Add(index);
                DrawItem(index);
                RedCounts += 1;
            }
            else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (!m_itemIndexes.Contains(index))
                    return;

                m_itemIndexes.Remove(index);
                DrawItem(index);
                OnItemRemoved(index, listBox1.Items[index].ToString());
            }  
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
        }

        protected virtual void OnItemRemoved(int indx, string name)
        {
            EventHandler<ItemEventArgs> handler = ItemRemoved;

            if(handler != null)
                ItemRemoved(this, new ItemEventArgs() {  Index = indx, Name = name});
        }

        private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            m_MyListColor = MyListColor;
            if (m_MyListColor.IsEmpty == true)
            {
                m_MyListColor = Color.Red;
            }

            bool selected = (e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected;

            if (m_itemIndexes.Contains(e.Index))
            {
                using (var brush = new SolidBrush(m_MyListColor))
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.DrawBackground();
            }

            string item = listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString();
            e.Graphics.DrawString(item, e.Font, selected || m_itemIndexes.Contains(e.Index) ? Brushes.White : Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);

            if (selected)
                e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }

        private void DrawItem(int index)
        {
            Rectangle rectItem = listBox1.GetItemRectangle(index);
            listBox1.Invalidate(rectItem);
        }

        [Browsable(true)]
        public Color MyListColor
        {
            get { return m_MyListColor; }
            set
            {
                m_MyListColor = value;
                Refresh();
            }
        }

        [Browsable(true)]
        public ListBox MyListBox
        {
            get { return listBox1; }
            set
            {
                listBox1 = value;
                Refresh();
            }
        }

        [Browsable(true)]
        public int RedCounts
        {
            get { return counter; }
            set
            {
                counter = value;
                Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void ListBoxControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    public class ItemEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't see you are calling `redcounts` to update the counter though...

Comment: Are you sure `counter` isn't defined in two places? What is the relationship between `lb1` and `listBox1` ?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but `ListBoxControl` is a UserControl which contains a ListBox, `listBox1`. ...Right?

Comment: I would search your code for `counter = 0`. You might have put it somewhere else or meant `==` instead. I *believe* you can also put a breakpoint on `counter` itself to see when the value changes.

Comment: Marc Gravell i just declared lb1 for the UserControl listBoxControl1 wich contain the listBox1. Declared lb1 in Form1 so i can use the properties in Form1.

Comment: in place of `counter += 1;` try `Redcounts += 1`. Just in case if it works.

Comment: @bonCodigo He's calling `counter += 1`, he shouldn't have to increment `RedCounts`.

Comment: Do you set the property "Redcounts" to zero somewhere else?

Comment: Verni no. Im not callung/using the RedCounts anywhere else.

Comment: Again I'd put a breakpoint in the setter and make absolutely *sure* it's never getting called with `0`.

Comment: Just edited my question and added there the code of the User Control maybe someone can test it with the counter and RedCounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no miracles, right click on `counter` somewhere in code -> "Find all references". If you can't see in results immediately where you initialize it with 0, set a break point on every occurrence and you will find it soon

Answer (score -4):

Your counter variable is always zero because every time your class is called all non-static objects will be instantiated again. You need to declare your counter variable as static such as `static int counter=0;

`

Comment: nonononono... do **not** try to "fix" things my making a field static. That has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: I found now that if i set the variable counter to public static and in form1 not declaring the lb1 as before and not using the property as before then it's working. That's not a solution since im not sure yet why it didn't work with the property. But if im using it as public static it's working. The question is still remain why it's 0 if im using it as before.

Comment: try adding  RedCounts = counter; below counter += 1;

Comment: @user1196715 Making the field static will make it effectively shared across all instances of your control (technically it's just not related to any instance, but to the static class instead). I'm 99.9999% sure this is *not* the behavior that you want. The fact that making it static makes it work though is a mystery.